# How so I create a QRCode reader that reads the information and stores it in the database

Tags: python, django, web, qr-code

I'm starting up a new project for an examination attendance that scans the qrcode of the students' identity card which contains the matriculation number and the full name information of the student. Is there a way to go about this because i am going to store the information inside the database and after the lecturer has logged in he scans twice the first time for sign-in and the second time for sign-out which would all be columns on the attendance table. Please what are your recommendations on how i should go about this project?

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to recognize the QR code from a camera that's linked to a personal computer (or will be processing captured footage on this computer after the session), you can use OpenCV: https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-qr-code-scanner-c-and-python/. Since you tagged Django, you'll be able to use python OpenCV to directly send recognition results to the database API.